# check field name of db exist string

Tags: php, mysql, database

is this possible to get the product names from database occur into string like below example:-

`SELECT product_name FROM table_name WHERE product_name IN ('hello Cannabicare hi Dread Rock Coffeeshop whatsup');`

in the above example Cannabicare and Dread Rock Coffeeshop are product name and can repeat multiple time becouse string generate dynamically on user post

in php i formed above query like

`$search_product_name='hello Cannabicare hi Dread Rock Coffeeshop whatsup';
$query="SELECT product_name  FROM table_name WHERE product_name IN ('".$search_product_name."')";`

string can contain `('|,|@|#|,| etc..)`.

Comment: what is your expectation ?

Comment: If you will be wanting to frequently search your product table you might want to look into [Full Text Search in the MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Just I have given key concept.

step1: explode your sentence(input)

step2: execute sql command depends on your splited array value

step3: push all the possible product name into your resultant array

For example:

```
$var = "your dynamic value";
$res = explode(" ",$var);
$prod_name = new array();
for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++){
    $word = $res[$i];
    $prod_name = mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM table_name WHERE product_name  LIKE '%".$word."%'");
    $productname = mysql_fetch_array($prod_name);
    array_push($prod_name,$productname);
}
print_r($prod_name);/* this is for just testing */
```

Comment: its a whole string but i need to get only product names exist in the string

Comment: i tried this but it gives very large no of records

Comment: Yes. That's why I am splitting sentence into array. Check with print $res..

Comment: Can you give one example very clearly

Comment: firstly user can post comment like facebook and in this post user can write one or more product names which exist in product_name field in product table in db but i don't know which product name he/her posted.In my next task i will have to hyperlink those product name in that string and for that we have to match each product name with string its very time consuming

Answer (score 0):

You have to give each product name as comma separated value. for example, if you want to search from products Cannabicare, Dread Rock Coffeeshop then you have to do like below

```
SELECT product_name FROM table_name WHERE product_name 
IN ('Cannabicare', 'Dread Rock Coffeeshop')
```

Comment: i can't do that because user post this mentioned string like fb comment and i don't know the names of products

Comment: then you have to first take out the product name from the fb comment and form the query like above

Comment: i have no criteria to identify product name

Comment: without criteria how can you identify product names

Comment: thats why i asked SELECT product_name FROM table_name WHERE product_name IN ('hello Cannabicare hi Dread Rock Coffeeshop whatsup'); like matching is possible in database query